# read_html in R intermittently fail to return content

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape below website but read_html returns "{xml_nodeset (0)}":

```
require(rvest)
URL <- "https://camelcamelcamel.com/BSN-SYNTHA-6-Protein-Micellar-
Isolate/product/B003YDWVNO?context=search"
p=read_html(URL)
html_nodes(p,"a")
```

Please note that this command works at times, but then stops ;/

Any help in understanding this erratic behavior is much appreciated.

Best,
Janush

Comment: I ran it 10 times, in 10 minute iterations (Sys.sleep(600), and had no problem at all. Perhaps when you ran it the server was down?

Comment: "stops". What does "stops" mean? Warning with 0-length or NULL return? An actual error/exception?

Comment: By stops I meant that the code was able to pull the data from this website and then after few attempts it stopped. I found out that I am actually being blocked ( I tried to scrape it in Python too). Any idea how to avoid being blocked ?